# How to setup Salesforce Identity Provider to work with Twilio Flex

Tags: lightning, single-sign-on, twilio, identity-provider

What is the process to setup Salesforce Identity Provider to work with a 3rd party like Twilio Flex?

Whenever I try to login, I get this error:

> Incorrect HTTP Method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To setup Salesforce Idenity Provider to work with Twilio Flex you need to complete these steps:

1. Create an self-signed certificate
2. Enable Salesforce Identity Provider
3. Create Twilio Flex Connected App
4. Setup SSO in Twilio Flex

---

### Create a self-signed certificate

1. Setup > Security > Certificate and Key Management
2. Press `Create Self-Signed Certificate` button
3. Give the certificate a `Label` and `Unique Name`, I used `SalesforceSSO`
4. `Key Size` of `2048`
5. `Exportable Private Key` should be ticked
6. `Use Platform Encryption` should **not** be ticked
7. Press `Save` button
8. Press `Download Certificate` button

### Enable Salesforce Identity Provider

1. Setup > Identity > Identity Provider
2. Press `Enable Identity Provider` button
3. Select `SalesforceSSO` certificate
4. Press `Save` button

### Create Twilio Flex Connected App

1. Setup > Apps > App Manager
2. Press `New Connected App` button
3. Set `Connected App Name` to `Twilio Flex`
4. Set `API Name` to `Twilio_Flex`
5. Set `Contact Email` to a suitable email address
6. In the `Web App Settings` section, set `Start URL` to `https://flex.twilio.com/agent-desktop/`
7. `Enable SAML` should be ticked
8. Set Entity Id to `https://preview.twilio.com/iam/Accounts/[ACCOUNT_SID]/saml2` remember to replace `ACCOUNT_SID`, you can find your on the [Twilio Project Dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/console)
9. Set `ACS URL` to the same as `Entity Id`
10. Set `Subject Type` to `User ID`
11. Set `Name ID Format` to `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent`
12. Set `Issuer` to `https://yourdomain.my.salesforce.com`
13. Set `IdP Certificate` to `SalesforceSSO`
14. `Verify Request Signatures` unticked
15. `Encrypt SAML Response` unticked
16. Press `Save` button
17. Add a New Custom Attributes
18. Key of `full_name`
19. Value of `$User.FirstName + " " + $User.LastName`
20. Add a New Custom Attributes
21. Key of `roles`
22. Value of `'agent'` (in quote marks)

### Setup SSO in Twilio Flex

1. Open the [Twilio Flex Single Sign-On](https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/users/single-sign-on)
2. Set `Friendly Name` to `SalesforceSSO`
3. Paste in the certificate you downloaded from Salesforce
4. Set `Identity Provider Issuer` to `https://yourdomain.my.salesforce.com`
5. Set `Single Sign-On URL` to `https://yourdomain.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect`
6. Set `Default Redirect URL` to `https://yourdomain.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect`
7. Press `Save` button

---

Finally, to use Twilio Flex from Salesforce, open Salesforce and access the phone from the utility bar.

To login using SSO it will ask for your runtime domain which can be found on the [Runtime Overview](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/overview)